# localhost redirected you too many times in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

I have googled for this but did not get anything that worked for my scenario So, I am posting my question. I am working on admin login using CodeIgniter MVC framework, I have written a base controller called 'Admin_Controller' for all my admin controllers which they extended from 'Admin_Controller' I have written login session check in my base controller that is 'Admin_Controller' **but it is not working properly saying "localhost redirected you too many times."**

Folder structure:

```
--controllers
   --admin/
     -- Banners.php
     -- Categories.php
     -------
     -------
     -- Login.php
 --models
   -- admin
      -- Mdl_banners.php
      -- Mdl_categories.php
      ------------
      --------------
 --views
   --admin
     -------
     -------
```

Login Form: admin/login/login_View.php

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/login/validate_user" method="post" name="login_form">
  <h1>Login</h1>
     <?php
        echo "<div class='error_msg'>";
        if (isset($error_message)) {
          echo $error_message;
        }
        echo validation_errors();
        echo "</div>";
     ?>
    <div>
     <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" required="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="password" name="user_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-default submit" name="submit_login">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Base Controller: core/MY_Controller.php

```php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    // modules::run('admin/login/isUserLoggedin');
  }
}
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_title = 'My Site Name';
    // check if user is logged in
    if (! $this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
      redirect('admin/login');
    }
  }
}
```

My Login Controller: Controllers/admin/Login.php

```php
class Login extends Admin_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/mdl_login');
  }

  public function index(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
      redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard'));
    $data['title'] = $this->_title . ' - Admin Login';
    $this->load->view('admin/login/login_view');
  }

  public function validate_user(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      $this->load->view('login_view');
    } else {
      $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('user_password'))
      );
      $result = $this->mdl_login->login($data);
      if ($result == TRUE) {
        $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $result = $this->mdl_login->read_user_information($user_name);
        if ($result != false) {
          $session_data = array(
            'user_id' => $result[0]->id,
            'user_name' => $result[0]->username,
            'email' => $result[0]->email,
          );
          // Add user data in session
          $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
          redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
      } else {
        $data = array(
          'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
        );
        $this->load->view('admin/login/login_view', $data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**My problem is It is showing as "localhost redirected you too many times."** **My doubt is that is there any problem to have 'Login' controller inside 'admin' folder in 'controllers'?** Anyone point me in right direction? Thanks.

Comment: That happens because of loop, please reformat your code so it's worth reading and digging. Where you show the login form? and the form would submit to `validate_user`

Comment: I have updated my question with login form, please check it once @Adi Prasetyo

Comment: aside from this q, you should use PHP [password-hashing API](https://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/) instead of md5. Do you able to see the form before redirect loop?

Comment: No I am unable to see the login form, If I access `http://localhost/site_name/admin/login` then it is showing the error as `localhost redirected you too many times.`

Comment: instead of redirect try to load view

Answer (score 0):

redirect('admin/login') will look for controller named Admin and method login. you can change to 'foo/bar' where foo is your desired controller and bar is the method.

given this function

```php
public function bar() {
  echo "I am about to show the login form here";
}
```

You can utilize [remap](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls) or [route](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

to break the redirect loop firstly understand the concept (use remap or routing) then you should modify your code to execute the above function.

Comment: but I dont have any controller named as "Admin" in my controllers, So Where can I write that function?

Comment: the usage of admin folder inside controller folder is?

Comment: to separate all admin controllers like for example `for categories, admin/categories.php` where `Categories.php` will have its own `index,add,update,delete` methods. Is this right way or not? Its working for all other admin pages like `categories` but not working for `login` page. You can understand this by seeing the 'folder structure' as I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & all the replies, I will try your answer and update you.